# Pandas - groupby where one column's value equals value in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where one column is a form of id while another column is basically a foreign key for the first column.

The dataframe is something like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"id" : ["b", "a", "c", "d", "e", "f"], "parent_id" : ["a", None, "a", None, "d", "d"]})

   id parent_id
0  b         a 
1  a        None
2  c         a
3  d        None
4  e         d
5  f         d
```

What i want to do is create groups of the form

```
   id parent_id
0  a        None  
1  b         a 
2  c         a
```

The id's themselves have no sort order so sorting, then filling the na's and taking the first entry in the group as the parent is not an option.

What I'm currently doing is

```
df = df.fillna("")
groups = df.groupby("parent_id")
parents = groups.get_group("")
for p_id, p in p.iterrows():
    grp = groups.get_group(p_id)
    do_something(p, grp)
```

Is there a better way to do this? One that does not involve the slow iterrows method.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Because if you were able to just take the top value you could do something like this: `df.fillna('').groupby('id')['parent_id'].head(1)`

Comment: Looks fine. If you are concerned about performance, then how big is the dataset you are using?

Comment: I want to create groups of the type shown in the question. Basically groups of a parent node and all it's children. The id column is unique.

Comment: @MartinValgur I have about 30k groups with about 5 to 100 members per group. It's not too slow. But I wanted to know if there was a better/more efficient way to do it.